# Composer psr-4 autoload class not found error after changing prefix

Tags: php, composer-php, psr-4

i've already been looking for solutions to my problem but could'nt find any so far.

```
{
    "name": "petersil98/thresh",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "type": "library",
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "Thresh\\": "src/"
        }
    }
}
```

This is my public/test.php:

```
<?php

require_once '../vendor/autoload.php';

use Thresh\Helper\Config;

Config::setPlatform("euw1");
```

And this is my src/Helper/Config.php:

```
<?php

namespace Thresh\Helper;

class Config{...}
```

This is the error i get: `Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'Thresh\Helper\Config' not found`

First i had my psr-4 autoload registered with the prefix 'src'

```
"autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "src\\": "src/"
        }
    }
```

After changing the psr-4 autoload prefix to **Thresh** (and updating the namespaces) and running `composer dump-autoload` it doesnt work anymore
**PS**: `composer dump-autoload` returns `Generated autoload files containing 0 classes`

Comment: Have you tried to delete the vendor folder and then run `composer install` again? And is the folder `src` in the same folder as your `composer.json`?

Comment: I deleted it now and rerun composer install, works now ty